# Variable value assign and retrieve

Tags: c#, variables, properties

How does variable assigning (setting) and retrieve value works in the background? For example:

```
{ 
   int myValue;
   myValue = 5; //here we assign value (set)
   Console.WriteLine(myValue); // here we retrieve value
}
```

So here we first declare value. In next line we assign value (does it work the same way as setting the property). Also, when retrieving value, does it work the same way as get in properties.

Next question:

If we have TextBox control, which has Text property.
Lets say, name of text box control is `myTextBox`.

```
myTextBox.Text = "Michael"; // here we set value
string result = myTextBox.Text; // here we retrieve (get) value
```

Does this works same as `{ get; set; }` method in fields-properties?

Comment: You should specify the language.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I added it, C#

Comment: Text IS a property on TextBox, and yes, assigning it and reading it with the get/set works just like having a variable and setting/getting it. I'm not sure what it is your asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the IL if you want. Here's a simple sample using linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    int i ;
    i=5 ;
    i.Dump();

    i_p = 6;
    i.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public int i_p {get; set;}
```

and here's the IL for it:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0004:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  ldarg.0     
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.6    
IL_000C:  call        UserQuery.set_i_p
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0013:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
IL_0018:  pop         
IL_0019:  ret         

get_i_p:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery.<i_p>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  br.s        IL_0009
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     
IL_000A:  ret         

set_i_p:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery.<i_p>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret
```

nothing too fancy happening there, if that is what you were asking.

The point of having properties is to avoid having public variables, and to enable you to encapsulate (read hide), your implementation.

So, using a property, you can in the setter alter it, apply validation logic,  change other variables, etc, (you shouldn't, btw), or better yet, in the future, if you need to change the backing variable type, you can do it without breaking public interfaces.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I asked for. I am beginner, and in one lesson of video tutorial teacher said it dumps value. And I never heard for term dump, so its clearly above what he was talking about. Thanks

Comment: We usually use "dump" to mean show on console, or whichever other output (log file, error stream , etc). Linqpad has a `Dump()` extension to allow you to easily see your values. Highly suggest you check it out, it's great.

Comment: Is Linqpad a third party tool? Looks great... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes it is. Here's an article I've wrote about it, has the links, and some tips you might find useful as a beginner :) [linqpad and visual studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/789481/Bridging-the-Gap-between-Linqpad-and-Visual-Studio)

Answer (score 1):

If you set a variable the memory that corresponds to the variable will be filled with the value you assign to that variable. If you use `{get; set;}` you are using what is called *autosetter/getter*. The compiler will automatically insert a private value. For example if you have

```
public int myVariable {get; set;}
```

The compiler will make this:

```
private int _myVariale;

public int myVariable{
    get {return _myVariale;}
    set {_myVariale = value;}
}
```

So the concept of properties is something that build on top of variables. You can see the C# properties with its `get` and `set` syntax also as API sugar. In other programming languages you will implement functions like `int GetMyVariable()` and `void SetMyVariable(int value)` to implement properties.

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking does concept of setting and retrieving variable values works the same way (in the background) as for properties. Thanks

Comment: Your variable correspond to an address in memory. Assign a variable means writing a value to that piece of memory. Assigning a value of one variable to another means copying the value of he memory belonging to the first variable to the memory of the other. I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for.